# Proof of a conjugate property

Tags: power, math

In power systems, I understand why S = V·I*. However, I am having a hard time understanding why I = S*/V*.

Can someone explain, or better yet prove, that I = S*/V*?

You don't have to prove it under power system conditions, I just want to know the property that falls under this conjugate proof.

Answer (score 4):

If it is known that S = V × I* (notation used here: \$\small S = V \cdot \overline I\$):

\$S = V \cdot \overline I \Rightarrow \$

\$\overline I = {S \over V}\Rightarrow \$

\$\overline {\overline I} = \overline {({S \over V})} \Rightarrow \$

\$I = \overline {({S \over V})} \Rightarrow \$

\$I = {\overline S \over \overline V} \$

Going from the third expression to the fourth uses *property I*, and going from the fourth to the fifth expression uses *property V*, as described, among other places, in the article *[Conjugate Complex Numbers](https://www.math-only-math.com/conjugate-complex-numbers.html)* on [Math-Only-Math](https://www.math-only-math.com/).

I don't know if those are the commonly used or standardised names/numbers for these properties, though.

Answer (score 2):

It can be shown directly by shuffling the phasors in the polar form. There the conjugate is got by changing the sign of the angle.
[image]

1. The starting point
2. The conjugate of the current is presented with the apparent power and voltage. The expression is presented in the polar form
3. The conjugate of the current is presented as the conjugate of another quantity.
4. The conjugate-operator is removed from both sides and the expression of the current is developed to the final form.